# Responsive. Changing <div> display order with CSS in media queries, float troubles and font-size

Tags: css, css-float, font-size, fluid-layout

I am working on this page:

http://www.analog.la/test/ret/index2.html

Basically there is a containing division with 5 within it. They are floated left to line up vertically but I am having a couple of problems with how to adjust my CSS in media queries (one for 768 and one for 480).

As you can see, the main order goes logo, hex1, middle, hex2, hex3.

**Float Troubles**

For 768 I would quite like to have logo and hex1 (centered), then middle below (centered) and hex2 and 3 (centered). But when I take the float off the middle, it is taken 'out of the float equation' and everything just kind of goes awkward! So I have set it up with no floats, but that is pushing the middle div too far down for my liking. Any tips would be massively appreciated!!

**Display Order**

For 480 and lower I would really like to shift the order of the divisions so that I can have the logo, then the 'middle' section and have the hex links following, but I don't know how to change the order via CSS. I saw a similar thread on here - however the person had used a provided grid and I have just put this together myself so it didn't seem to apply.

**Font-size**

Just wondering if there is anyway to have font-size (for headers) be responsive to page width? It's not really high priority but it would be good to know!

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: you can use set font varying font sizes in your media query css for different resolutions and better to use it in %

Comment: Yeah, I had thought that, I was just wondering if there was a way to have it gradually change in response to the screen width rather than using media queries (as this would mean a higher variety of media queries as there are quite a number of breakpoints that soley effect title text!). 

In regards to using % for font-size...what is it a percentage of? I tried it for the footer text and it needed to be 2000%! So I changed it back to 2em.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the floats:
try making your .links1 and .links2 divs 100% width and adding a css clearfix to them to clear the floats. That might fix the formatting issue with the .preorder div. To center the hexagons, you can try adding a text-align:center rule to the .links1 and .links2 divs as well.

Here's an article on clearfix from chris coyner's site: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

For the font size:
if you want to gradually change it as the window resizes, check out fitText: http://fittextjs.com/ -- it requires some tweaking to get it to work nicely but it seems like this is the effect you're looking for.

Also, it looks like you might need a clearfix on your .container div